# how to sort by navigation property (collection)

Tags: c#, performance, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-6

How to sort by navigation property field ( entity framework )  if the navigation property is  collection
i want to sort employees list by Date and the date in the navigation property (collection)
[image: )]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If Trans represents a collection of something like NameValue pairs where one is something like the EmployeeStartDate:

```
employees.OrderBy(x => x.Trans.Single(t => t.Name == "EmployeeStartDate").Date));
```

This is just an example and assumes that the Trans collection does always contain an required matching entry.

If the Trans is just a collection of dates, then you need to decide on which date to use. Such as the Minimum or Maximum date. For example, to order by the earliest date:

```
employees.OrderBy(x => x.Trans.Min(t => t.Date));
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answer given by @Steve Py, you can also **select the result first and then sort the field** you want.

The following is the demo:

```
        employees = (employees.Select(d => new Employee 
                      {
                        Name= d.Name,
                        Trans= d.Trans.OrderBy(e=>e.Date).ToList()
                      })).ToList();
```

Model:

```
public class Employee
{
    [Key]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Trans> Trans{ get; set; }
}

public class Trans
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
}
```